# Is there a way to email orders to someone other than the email address that the customer entered?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to do the various code for the email setup other then customer but its not working.

I try with the different solutions but none of that work?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_custom_email_cc', 10, 3 );

function add_custom_email_cc( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Add your custom CC email address
    $custom_cc_email = 'cc_email@example.com';

    if ( $email_id == 'customer_processing_order' || $email_id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $custom_cc_email . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```